# Crashlytics NDK How to Enable native symbol uploading

Tags: firebase, android-ndk, crashlytics

I am tring to enable crashlytics for my NDK android app. Ive followed the [the guide here.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/ndk-reports) I got stuck on Step 2.

> **Step 2: Enable native symbol uploading To produce readable stack:**
> traces from NDK crashes, Crashlytics needs to know about the symbols
> in your native binaries. Our Gradle plugin includes the
> uploadCrashlyticsSymbolFileBUILD_VARIANT task to automate this process
> (to access this task, make sure nativeSymbolUploadEnabled is set to
> true).
>
> For method names to appear in your stack traces, you must explicitly
> invoke the uploadCrashlyticsSymbolFileBUILD_VARIANT task after each
> build of your NDK library. For example:

```
>./gradlew app:assembleBUILD_VARIANT\
           app:uploadCrashlyticsSymbolFileBUILD_VARIANT
```

What does `For method names to appear in your stack traces, you must explicitly invoke the uploadCrashlyticsSymbolFileBUILD_VARIANT task after each build of your NDK library.`mean? I also saw that they left a line with `gradlew`. Is this a command on a command line? I am very lost. Can anyone help me achieve step 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add "nativeSymbolUploadEnabled true" to your gradle file like mentioned in [Step1](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/ndk-reports#update-gradle-config) this will instruct the gradle plugin to generate a new task with the format "uploadCrashlyticsSymbolFileBUILD_VARIANT" for each build type and architectures. Check this screenshot where I only have one build type "release" but also have three architectures. The tasks generated are:

1. uploadCrashlyticsSymbolFileArm8Release
2. uploadCrashlyticsSymbolFileUniversalRelease
3. uploadCrashlyticsSymbolFileX86_64Release

[image]

To run these tasks, you will need to either execute the command in a terminal updated for the desired build variant, e.g.

```
>./gradlew app:assembleX86_64\
       app:uploadCrashlyticsSymbolFileX86_64Release
```

Or manually calling those tasks in the gradle tab. They need to be executed in this order (first the assemble and then the uploadCrashlyticsSymbolFile...) to make sure the binaries have been created for Crashlytics to generate and upload the symbol files.

To answer your question: What does For method names to appear in your stack traces, you must explicitly invoke the uploadCrashlyticsSymbolFileBUILD_VARIANT task after each build of your NDK library.mean? Crashlytics will need the symbol files in order to convert the crash report into a readable stack trace with method names and line numbers.

Comment: Very good explanation. Do I need to do this every time I change my gradle and resync gradle? Or is doing this 1 time (after adding crashlitics ndk) okay?

Comment: You will need to run those gradle tasks (assemble and uploadCrahslyticsSymbolFile...) every time you need to build the app, specially if there are changes to the native code. When there are changes in the code, the binaries will be different after compiling too and Crashlytics will need the new symbols for those changes.

Comment: Is there a way to automate this? It seems very prone to forgetting

Comment: I think gradle can be instructed to run tasks with a specified order, but I'm not very familiar with it. I think is related to that: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html

Answer (score 4):

I was also at a lost, but finally understand.

This command should be like this.

At first, move to the directory

```
cd /YourProjectRootPath/proj.android/
```

You can find gradlew file in this directory.

Then execute gradlew to run two tasks.

Task1: assembleDebug or assembleRelease

Task2: uploadCrashlyticsSymbolFileDebug or uploadCrashlyticsSymbolFileRelease

the command is, (Example of debug)

```
./gradlew XXXXXX:assembleDebug XXXXXX:uploadCrashlyticsSymbolFileDebug
```

Please replace "XXXXXX" to your "app name".

If you don't know what is your app name, please run the command below.

```
./gradlew tasks --all
```

You can see all task names and can find these two tasks.

XXXXXX:assembleDebug
XXXXXX:uploadCrashlyticsSymbolFileDebug

This "XXXXXX" is your "app name".

I don't know why Google describes such a complicated command using ">" and "\", but it's just a simple command,

```
./gradlew <TASK1> <TASK2>
```